# React js Sort table is not updating the table

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I implemented this function:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState(dataList);

    const handleSortName = () => {
        const newData = data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)); 
        console.log(newData)
        setData(newData);
    }
```

and on my html I have:

```
{ data.length > 0 && data.map((row, i) => (
   <table>
   {/* ...items */}
   </table>
))}
```

if I clicked on sort I can see through console that the table was order by name, but on the view did't order by name, why?? the `setData` don't updated de new data on table view???

Comment: `setData([...newData])`